# Use HTML in a category title

Tags: categories

I need to use a superscript registered symbol ( <sup>®</sup> ) in a category title.

There is no unicode character for a superscripted ® and I can't figure out a way to make the category title allow HTML.

Has anyone got a work around for this?

Comment: Have you considered a client side javascript solution to find and replace ® with <sup>®</sup>?

Comment: Yes I've just implemented one but it's really not an ideal solution.

Comment: How about not using the category title? Create a custom category field and use that to display as the title instead? Or does that have the same restriction?

Comment: Hmm. I like that idea. Not sure if it would have the same restriction. From a client simplicity point of view it might not be ideal but I like your thinking!

Answer (score 0):

Have you check [CE String](http://docs.causingeffect.com/expressionengine/ce-string/index.html)? It allows you to manipulate strings (text) with very simple syntax. In the User guide take a look at the Custom Methods.